# Unable to ping another VLAN from Proxmox VM running docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, proxmox

I am having trouble communicating from a Proxmox VM running Ubuntu to a NSA on a different VLAN. This issue is only happening with this specific VM.  I have other VMs on the same box that can ping the other VLN just fine.  One strange thing I am noticing is when I attempt to ping the NAS the 'From' IP address is not correct:

```
PING 192.168.30.17 (192.168.30.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.16.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.16.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

192.168.16.1 is not the IP of the VM.  Here is my ifconfig:

```
br-bdc324865e7c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        ether 02:42:05:de:59:9f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-e6ff6afcb423: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:1fff:fe6e:32bf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:1f:6e:32:bf  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 664  bytes 2500219 (2.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 582  bytes 106273 (106.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ea68e1731716: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:2d:22:ff:68  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ee877fa76586: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255
        ether 02:42:39:6f:43:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-fd077aeb7a68: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        ether 02:42:fc:7f:81:b1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:ffff:fe62:814  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:ff:62:08:14  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8251  bytes 17989335 (17.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8149  bytes 5781191 (5.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens18: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.123  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::84e1:2aff:fefb:8b37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 86:e1:2a:fb:8b:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32519  bytes 11182404 (11.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2277  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12508  bytes 23008661 (23.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As you can see I am running docker on this VM so there are a bunch of other interfaces including 192.168.16.1.  Why is that interface there and why is it using that to ping the NAS?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out docker compose was creating the bad network. I don't know why or how it started doing that, but after removing it everything worked again.